# PyScripter and PEP 8 settings

Tags: python, pyscripter

What are the specific settings in PyScripter that can make your code conform to the PEP 8 specs? I'm happy to go through this manually. Just thought someone on here might have done this already and have them ready at hand. Alternatively is there an IDE that has templates set up that conform to coding conventions?

Is [pep8 checker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) my only solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i also use PyScripter but i use [PyLint](http://www.logilab.org/857) externally to check my code, which helps me to add the documentations and other little issues to be solved later rather than the PyScripter to show me red lines all the time.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. I think this will solve my problems :)